# Extract list of properties from AD user objects to XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm using this powershell script, https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Extract-arbitrary-list-of-6f59d3b4, to extract properties from AD user objects.

When I run this command:

.\Get-UserADProperties2.ps1 givenName,sn,department,mail,telephoneNumber -searchroot 'LDAP://ou=users,ou=EMP,dc=emp,dc=company,dc=com' | Export-Clixml C:\XML\ADInfo.xml

the tags in the xml file look like this:

```
  <Obj RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <S N="department">Information Systems</S>
      <S N="mail">jane.doe@company.com</S>
      <S N="sn">Doe</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
```

How can I get the export so the tags look like this:

```
<Obj RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <department>Information Systems</department>
      <mail>jane.doe@company.com</mail>
      <lname>Doe</lname>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
```

Answer (score 0):

Export-clixml is used for serializing an object so it can be read back in later. If you want pretty html use something like convertto-html. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx

Comment: `ConvertTo-Html` creates HTML, not XML.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers my bad, didn't realize it needed to be xml. If you want your own custom xml markup, you'll have to do it by hand. This post will point you in the right direction:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935102/powershell-custom-property-xml-tags-with-convertto-xml-output

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```psh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\XML\ADInfo.xml'

$xml.SelectNodes('//MS/S') | % {
  $node = $xml.CreateElement($_.N)
  $txt  = $xml.CreateTextNode($_.'#text')
  [void]$node.AppendChild($txt)

  $_.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($node, $_)
}

$xml.Save('C:\XML\ADInfo.xml')
```